# asp.net MVC - @HTML.Raw writes out model to page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.net MVC 4 (Razor) application.  We are using Dojo's  1.9 Gridx to display data.

My controller returns my model to the view.  To work with the model on the client side, I usually will assign it to javascript variable as so:

```
var _model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

I can then pass the _model to Dojo's Gridx control.  What I don't like is if you view the source in a browser, the data in _model is visible on the page.  Is seeing the _model data in the browser by design?  or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do it (not sure if it's better), is to send your model to your view via the standard `@model MyModel`, serialize it to JSON and set it as a value of an `input` element, and then grab the value of the `input` via Javascript. Then you can destroy/remove the `input` element, and that data won't be visible in the browser source anymore.

Example:

**In Razor View**

```
@model MyModel

<input type="hidden" id="myViewModel" value="@Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)" />
```

**In Your Javascrip File**

```
$(function(){
     var _model = JSON.parse($('#myViewModel').val());

     $('#myViewModel').remove();
});
```

Doing it your way or this way, the entirety of the model's data will still be in the page's source (and hence visible to anyone looking) - even if it's for a short amount of time. Always remember that when considering security for your application.

Comment: Right, I don't want the model's data to be visible in the page's source.  I can still view the model's data even when assigned to the hidden field and removing it doesn't work.

Comment: @alpha What do you mean, exactly, by removing it doesn't work? If you call `$(element).remove()`, then, as per the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/remove/), that element and all of it's children will be removed. With the code above, you'll be left with your entire viewmodel (in JSON) in the `_model` variable and you won't be able to see any viewmodel data in the page's source.

Comment: @alpha If all you want to do is get the viewmodel data into a Javascript variable so that you can use it with some Javascript framework, have you considered fetching the viewmodel via WebAPI? Or just returning it as JSON with an MVC JSONResult? Both of those options would completely bypass putting any data directly into the DOM

Comment: remove() does not remove it at all.  I tried remove() and setting the val(''). The element is still there.  Returning it as JSONResult and/or fetching via WebAPI works, too. Thanks!